# Паттерн repository и смена ORM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, dao, dapper

Знаю, что подобных вопросов было много, но ответа в них для себя, к сожалению, найти не смог. Вероятно буду писать глупости, не судите строго, я еще учусь)

Если использовать GenericRepository с Entity Framework в связке с UnitOfWork, то для того, что бы делать сложные запросы с несколькими join нам придется делать тип возвращаемого значения IQuerable а не IEnumerable, что в свою очередь подходит только для тех ORM, которые поддерживают Query Builder.

А Если например делать реализацию для Dapper, то я вообще не понимаю, как можно делать сложные запросы, если считать что Repository это in-memory коллекция доменных объектов. Т.е. я имею ввиду, что либо придется сначала загружать всю коллекцию объектов из базы в память, либо изобретать свою версию Query Builder для ОРМ, с помощью каких нибудь спецификаций. Вообще реально ли использовать Repository с Dapper или чистым SQL, учитывая, что существует постоянная необходимость джойнить несколько таблиц?

Хочу уточнить, что задаю этот вопрос именно в рамках паттерна Repository а не DAO.

Comment: _постоянная необходимость джойнить_ - значит, нужно в репозитории сделать метод, который возвращает сджойненные данные.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Первое и главное, что нужно понять про *Репозиторий* — он возвращает *сущности* предметной области, даже более того — не просто сущности, а *агрегаты*.

Для примера рассмотрим сайт с зарегистрированными пользователями. У пользователей есть идентификатор, логин и пароль.

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Замечательный класс *сущности*, который легко отобразить на таблицу в БД. К сожалению, такая лобовая реализация нарушает все принципы ООП. В частности, пароль пользователя не может быть изменён, если пользователь не знает старый пароль. Точно также идентификатор пользователя не должен меняться вообще, а смена логина может потребовать серьёзного сценария с поиском дубликата в БД.

Класс-сущность должен выглядеть так:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public string Login { get; }

    private string _password;

    public void ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        if (_password != oldPassword)
            throw new Exception();

        _password = newPassword;
    }

    internal User(int id, string login, string password)
    {
        Id = id;
        Login = login;
        _password = password;
    }
}
```

Такой класс реализует бизнес-логику. Это сущность предметной области. Его можно было бы отобразить на таблицу в БД «как есть», если не думать о безопасности. Рекомендации OWASP предлагают в частности, никогда не хранить пароли в открытом виде, а хранить их хеши, более того, для вычисления хешей использовать случайную затравку.

Для хранения в базе нам потребуется другой класс с отличной структурой. Поскольку он используется для связи объекта в БД, мы будем считать его *объектом переноса данных* (data transfer object — DTO).

```
class UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public byte[] Salt { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь у нас есть класс предметной области `User` и объект переноса данных `UserDto`, с помощью которого мы можем складывать пользователей в базу. Обратите внимания, мы не накладываем сейчас никаких особых ограничений на то, где именно будут храниться пользователи. `UserDto` определяет только, какие поля должны в конце концов сохраняться.

Класс `User` можно переписать с учётом существования `UserDto`:

```
class User
{
    private UserDto _dto;

    private User(UserDto dto)
    {
        _dto = dto;
    }

    public int Id => _dto.Id;

    public string Login => _dto.Login;

    public void ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        var hash = CalculateHash(oldPassword, _dto.Salt);

        if (!hash.SequenseEqual(_dto.PasswordHash))
            throw new Exception();

        _dto.PasswordHash = CalculateHash(newPassword, _dto.Salt);
    }
}
```

Теперь посмотрим, где в этой схеме появляется *репозиторий*. Репозиторий позволяет полностью скрывать детали хранения. Единственное, что мы должны знать о хранилище — оно большое, поэтому мы не можем загрузить все объекты в память.

На уровне предметной области — то есть физически в том же проекте, где объявлены `User` и `UserDto` мы описываем только интерфейс репозитория.

```
interface IUserRepository
{
    User Create(string login, string password);

    User GetById(int id);

    User GetByLogin(string login);

    User UpdateLogin(int id, string login);
}
```

Этот интерфейс может быть реализован с помощью ADO, Dapper, EF или любым другим способом. Вы можете хранить пользователей в SQL Server, Postres, MongoDB и даже в XML-файле, если их не очень много.

Создаём новый проект, скажем, для репозиториев ADO.

```
class AdoUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private Func<SqlConnection> _connectionFactory;

    public AdoUserRepository(Func<SqlConnection> connectionFactory)
    {
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    User GetById(int id)
    {
        using (var connection = _connectionFactory())
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE Id = @Id";
            command.Parameters.Add("@Id", id);
            . . .
        }
    }
}
```

Построение запросов и отображение данных из запросов в `UserDto` решаются на уровне конкретных репозиториев. Если у вас EF, то репозитории получаются простые.

У нас остался важный практический вопрос: если мы заполнили `UserDto`, кто превратит этот объект в доменную сущность `User`? В книге про паттерны GoF описан паттерн `Memento`, который как раз занимается сохранением и восстановлением объектов.

Логика `Memento` отличается от того, что нужно нам, но не кардинально, поэтому свою реализацию класса для сохранения и восстановления мы можем называть `Mememto`. Это будет отдельный класс, чтобы не нагружать `User` второй ответственностью. И, поскольку он должен иметь доступ к приватным членам класса `User`, он будет вложенным.

```
public class User
{
    private UserDto _dto;

    public static class Memento
    {
        public static UserDto Serialize(User domain) => domain._dto;

        public static User Deserialize(UserDto dto) => new User(dto);
    }
}
```

Теперь реализации репозиториев, например `AdoUserRepository` может вызывать `User.Memento.Deserialize`, чтобы создать `User` из `UserDto`.

```
User GetById(int id)
{
    using (var connection = _connectionFactory())
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE Id = @Id";
        command.Parameters.Add("@Id", id);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new Exception();

        return User.Memento.Deserialize(new UserDto
        {
            Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
            Login = reader.GetString(1),
            PasswordHash = reader.GetBytes(),
            Salt = reader.GetBytes(),
        });
    }
}
```

Последний вопрос о том, почему я подчеркнул разницу между *сущностями* и *агрегатами*. Агрегат это составная сущность, элементы которой не сильно нужны друг без друга. В базе такая сущность хранится в нескольких таблицах, но в предметной области это один большой объект, содержащий другие сущности или их коллекции.

Представим, что у наших пользователей есть профиль. Это набор параметров ключ-значение, которых не очень много. Мы могли бы всегда подгружать эти параметры, при загрузке пользователя. Если мы делаем так, мы прячем от бизнес-логики такие детали, как таблицы, связи, внешние ключи. Конечно, все они остаются на уровне реализации, но наверх не проникают.

Вот так можно загрузить агрегат вместе с дочерними параметрами с помощью энергичной загрузки EF (метод `Include`):

```
User GetById(int id)
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory())
    {
        var dto = context.Users
                         .Include(x => x.Parameters)
                         .Single(x => x.Id == id);

        return User.Memento.Deserialize(dto);
    }
}
```

Как видим, реализация может быть посложнее и попроще. EF пошлёт в базу один запрос и сумеет корректно отобразить значения полей на свойства `UserDto`. Мы сами могли бы послать два запроса в базу и реализовать простой мапинг, если бы использовали ADO.

В любом случае, это деталь реализации, про которую мы можем не думать на уровне предметной области.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ, я в целом со всем согласен, правда осталось пара вопросов: 1) Почему объект предметной области (доменный объект User) содержит элементы бизнес логики? Ведь по идее, эта ответственность должна быть на слое BL. 2) Чем тогда в данном случае это будет отличаться от паттерна DAO ведь помимо CRUD-операций рано или поздно в таких репозиториях будут появляться всякие навроде GetUserByParameter()?

Comment: @АлександрКубит Отвечу в двух комментариях. Сначала на первый вопрос. Слой бизнес-логики (business logic layer) и слой предметной области (domain layer) — это одно и то же. Второе название более современное, пришедшее из DDD. Мне кажется, оно более точное, потому что business logic относится к бизнес-приложениям, но в действительности трёхзвенная архитектура может использоваться и в компьютерных играх, и в социальных сетях. Это логика, но не бизнес-логика.

Comment: @АлександрКубит. Второй вопрос: в чём отличие репозиториев от DAO? Отличие в направлении зависимостей. В классической 3-хзвенной схеме они всегда направлены сверху вниз: от уровня представления к уровню бизнес-логики и от него к уровню доступа к данным. Это означает, что объекты `SqlCommand`, `DataSet`, `QueryBuilder` вызывались из предметной области. Это усложняло программу, так как помимо основной логики (скажем, бухгалтерской), вам приходилось держать рядом логику доступа к данным. В репозитории же все методы растут из пользовательских сценариев и там деталей хранения нет совсем.

Comment: Я вам очень благодарен за подробные разъяснения. Вы могли бы посоветовать что почитать или посмотреть по той архитектуре которую предлагаете вы? Я почти всегда воспринимал именно классическую 3-уровневую архитектуру. В вашем же случае реализация интерфейсов репозиториев происходит над слоем предметной области, если я не ошибаюсь на инфраструктурном слое, тогда получается там же и лежат интерфейсы сервисов и DTO для уровня представления?

Comment: @АлександрКубит, `User`, `UserDto` и `IUserRepository` можно размещать в одном проекте, это уровень предметной области или бизнес-логики. `AdoUserRepository` или `EfUserRepository` находятся в другом проекте, который зависит от первого проекта. Это уровень доступа к данным, или, как говорит Эванс, инфраструктурный уровень. По книгам дайте мне немного времени, я наверное структурирую ответ.

Comment: @АлександрКубит, составил список книг и сделал описание. http://markshevchenko.pro/2019/10/23/application-design-and-architecture-books/

Answer (score 1):

> Вообще реально ли использовать Repository с Dapper или чистым SQL,
>   учитывая, что существует постоянная необходимость джойнить несколько
>   таблиц?

Паттерн репозиторий можно использовать с любым источником данных. Даже если это сетевой ресурс или файл.

Более того, репозиторий не должен знать ничего о физической структуре данных и способе их хранения. Для этого есть источник данных и их объектная модель. Задача репозитория предоставить фасадный интерфейс к данным.

Comment: Да реально то реально, вопрос же не в этом. Я могу писать SQL реализацию репозитория для сущности, которая выступает корнем агрегатора сущностей, прописать там все join, но это будет уже DAO, т.к. в моем случае, это уже будет не доменный объект. А могу написать реализацию для каждого доменного объекта, тогда для того, что бы сделать join мне придется загрузить все объекты сначала в память, но это лишняя затрата ресурсов

Comment: @АлександрКубит а зачем join делать в репозитории? Его надо делать на стороне БД. В репозитории формируете нужный запрос SQL и отправляете на сервер БД, там вся магия и происходит. Разве не так?

Comment: Я не собираюсь выполнять join в репозитории, на entity это будет формирование через linq, на ADO это будет запрос написанный вручную, они будут содержать join, но выполняться он будет на уровне БД